# Is there a time mechanism that can be added to an NXT program?

Tags: nxt, programming, automation

I wanted to create a system where an NXT block would be set into function at a certain time of day (maybe 5:00 and then 5:10 and so on). I would want the timing function to be embedded into the NXT program. Is this a possible function? I have looked for documentation on the web but have not found anything useful..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the actual time of day, you can use the [mindsensors.com Realtime Clock Sensor](http://mindsensors.com/index.php?module=pagemaster&PAGE_user_op=view_page&PAGE_id=77).

Answer (score 2):

Time is thought of as a sensor value, measured in seconds. The Timer sensor can be used directly, as part of a Wait For block, as part of a Loop block.

Comment: Is there a numerical limit to the sensor block? It seems 86,400 seconds between each function is quite a long time.

Comment: 86400 seconds is a long time for an NXT.  I think mine shuts down after ten minutes of inactivity.  If it can be set to never shut down, how long do the batteries last?